# Why did connection failed: Temporary failure in name resolution, No matching distribution found for fastapi>=0.89.0?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, fastapi

I am trying to install FASTAPi with docker-compose

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  fastapi_app:
    build:
      context: ./backend
    image: fastapi_app:latest
    ports:
      - target: 8000
        published: 8000
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./backend/app
        target: /app
    networks:
      - websocket

  angular:
    image: node:18.13.0-alpine
    working_dir: /frontend
    ports:
      - target: 4200
        published: 4200
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./frontend
        target: /frontend
    networks:
      - websocket
    command: npm start

networks:
  websocket:
    name: websocket
    driver: bridge
```

My Dockerfile(backend)

```
FROM python:3.11
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /app/requirements.txt
COPY ./app /app
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

and requirements

```
fastapi>=0.89.0
uvicorn[standard]>=0.20.0,<0.21.0
```

I got this error

```
> [4/5] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /app/requirements.txt:                                       
11.60 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fb48a1ad890>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/fastapi/                   
2

69.15 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement fastapi>=0.89.0 (from versions: none)
69.15 ERROR: No matching distribution found for fastapi>=0.89.0
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: It's a networking problem, not a software issue.

Comment: @snakecharmerb How to check that?